# Can't mount raid sas hd after damage raid controller, wrong fs type?

Tags: mount

My RAID controller on an HP ProLiant DL380 G7 is damaged, and I am currently unable to repair it.

I have removed the hard drive from the server and connected it to a laptop via a USB connection.

The hard drive was originally running Windows Server 2016 with an NTFS file system.

My goal is to backup two specific files from this hard drive, nothing else.

I have tried to mount the hard drive on Debian Linux using the command:

`mount /dev/sdd /home/pe/backup`

I encountered the following error message:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd, missing codepage.....
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock
```

I have tried various solutions mentioned in a post, but none have worked so far.

How can I successfully mount the hard drive on my laptop to access and save these two files?

When I use the `lsblk` command, I only see `/dev/sdd`.

Does this mean the disk is damaged? Is it still possible to access the disk using Linux, or is it beyond repair?

I have noticed that out of the three disks, only one shows partitions (`sdx1`, `sdx2`, `sdx3`). Does this indicate that the other disks are also damaged?

I would greatly appreciate any help and solutions you can provide.

Comment: I don't think Windows allows using a disk without setting up a partition table on it, so trying to mount the whole-disk device `/dev/sdd` is most likely a non-starter. You should use a partition device, like `/dev/sdd2` instead.

Comment: but i see only /dev/sdd with lsblk is the disk destroyed? how can i mount this with debian i need access on this disk?

Comment: Is this normal on a raid system that you have only /dev/sdX and not /dev/sdX1 ?

Comment: What type of RAID were you using (0 or 1)?

Comment: first 2 disks = 1 virtual raid 0 and < sync raid 1> to second 2 disks = 1 virtual raid 0 |

Comment: So you're going to need to move both disks from the appropriate pair and then use mdadm (if it supports the on-disj raid format) o recreate the RAID 0. Then, and only then, you can attempt to mount the filesystem

Comment: Will i lost my data on the disks?

Comment: to get access i need both disks?

Comment: It's likely you need both disks of the pair, yes. That's the trade-off with using RAID 0: more space and more speed but less overall reliability

Comment: "_this means the disks are damaged?_" - no. It means you need to assemble them as a raid 0 in the same way that they were created. Remember, the partition table will only be at the beginning of the virtual (combined) "disk", so only on one physical disk

Comment: If the RAID controller (a HP SmartArray P410i is standard on a DL380 G7) uses the standard DDF metadata format, then you should be able to do a `mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdd /dev/<other half of the RAID0 pair>` or something similar to get the RAID0 set presented as a single device. This is a necessity:  with two-disk RAID0, your data is split into stripes, and all odd stripes are on one physical disk, and all even stripes on the other. If you access just one disk of the pair, you get only half of the stripes and your data will be full of holes.

Comment: Thank you for that @telcoM I wasn't sure how `mdadm` would need to be used to build a softRAID instance, so I wasn't able to provide the advice you've just given

Comment: Thank you both@roaima @telcoM for the help and the information I've learned a lot about it,  I'm not sure if I can do it that's probably beyond my current abilities. didn't create this raid I'll try it in the next few days and post the status here